# Haskell: Does ghci show "Chunk .. Empty"?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#bytestrings) has a code example like this:

```
ghci> B.pack [99,97,110]  
Chunk "can" Empty
```

(`B` stands for `Data.ByteString.Lazy`)

But my `ghci` does not show `Chunk` and `Empty` data constructors.

```
> B.pack [99,97,110]  
"can"
```

Did Haskell developers change the way the values of `ByteString` are printed?

Comment: What is your version? My 7.4.2 works as LYAH said.

Comment: Mine is 7.4.2 too though. I am using Windows. Does it matter?

Comment: Ha, me too, so probably no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like Duncan added hand-written `Show` instance for lazy `ByteString` somewhere between `0.9.2.1` and `0.10.0.1`. See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Internal.html#ByteString

Add: [Here](http://handra.rampa.sk/dawb/patch?repoPURL=http://darcs.haskell.org/bytestring/&repoPHash=20111106165851-5c91e-56b3f62ba43c6e8037a45d5cd841322fbf8da55d) is the relevant patch

Answer (score 4):

Old versions of `BL.ByteString` simple have a [`deriving Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.4/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Internal.html#ByteString) in their `data` declaration. This results in the GHCi output as shown in LYAH, and ensures the output is valid Haskell code. The nice plain string `"can"` isn't really a valid Haskell representation of that bytestring – that is, not a valid *Haskell 98* representation. However, it is common to use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` in modules that use bytestrings, which makes it valid. Which is probably the reason that there is now (since `0.10`) this nicer-to-read manual instance.