# Haskell: how to add a patch?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm in the IO chapter of Learn You a Haskell and noticed a discrepancy in how Bytestrings are displayed for me vs. the screenshots in the book (see below for an example).  Unless folks have other suggestions, it seems that the solution (at least, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305832/haskell-does-ghci-show-chunk-empty)) is to install [this patch](http://handra.rampa.sk/dawb/patch?repoPURL=http://darcs.haskell.org/bytestring/&repoPHash=20111106165851-5c91e-56b3f62ba43c6e8037a45d5cd841322fbf8da55d).

It's probably a pretty basic question but...how do I go about installing this type of patch?

Am of course open to other suggestions as well re: how to have ghci display the correct ByteString format.

---

My setup/system:

- ghci 7.6.3 (installed via Haskell Platform)
- Xubuntu 14 (VirtualBox)

---

How ByteStrings are displayed in the book.  (Note: we can assume that the author loaded a script containing the following `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B`.)

```
ghci> B.cons 85 $ B.pack [80,81,82,84]
Chunk "U" (Chunk "PQRT" Empty)
```

How ByteStrings are displayed on my computer:

```
Prelude> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
Prelude B> B.cons 85 $ B.pack [80,81,82,84]
"UPQRT"
```

Comment: That patch was for showing how it went from a derived instance of `Show` to a hand-written instance.  Basically, the version used by LYAH is older than the one you're using, and the one you're using is correct.  The new behavior is to print out the bytestring as if it is just a normal string, rather than as the underlying data constructors.  This is probably to align with the `OverloadedStrings` extension that makes it so that `ByteString`s can be written as `String` literals.

Comment: Oh okay.  Well, is there any way to see the specific `Chunk`s created by the compiler for a particular Lazy ByteString?

Comment: Also, can you please make your post an answer?  :)

Comment: @buckling by "the version used by LYAH" I assume you mean the version of GHCI, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patch you're referencing is showing the difference between an older and newer version of bytestring, where the newer version uses the hand-written `Show` instance.  You shouldn't be installing it, it's just that LYAH needs a few updates here and there (Haskell development has moved pretty fast in the last few years).

The `ByteString` constructors have actually been made private, you can't use them directly.  Because of this, the `Show` instance should output a `String` that can be turned back into a `ByteString`, and the easiest way is by using `pack` or the `OverloadedStrings` extension.

There is the `toChunks` function in `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, but I'm not sure it does exactly what you want.  Basically, you should consider the `ByteString` implementation to be private and only use the exported library functions to ensure that you don't break anything.  This would be equivalent to wanting to see the internals of `Data.Map.Map`, it just wouldn't be pretty to work with.